# Error creating new outlook email from the server

Tags: c#

I have a function that can create a new email in outlook and it works fine when running on my local machine. However, when deployed to the server i get the error shown below.

This is what it looks like when I run the code on my local machine: 
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGwiO.png). Is it possible to make this code run on the server and generate emails for users?

**Error:**

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)). at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType objectType) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType serverType) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj) at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) at MyProjectName.btnEmailEstimate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\My\Project\location\MyProjectName.ascx.cs:line 9833

**Here is my code:**

```
    protected void btnEmailEstimate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            List<string> lstAllRecipients = new List<string>();
            //Below is hardcoded - can be replaced with db data
            lstAllRecipients.Add("test1@testmail.com");
            lstAllRecipients.Add("test2@testmail.com");

            Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            Outlook.Inspector oInspector = oMailItem.GetInspector;

            // Recipient
            Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMailItem.Recipients;
            foreach (String recipient in lstAllRecipients)
            {
                Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(recipient);
                oRecip.Resolve();
            }

            //Add CC
            Outlook.Recipient oCCRecip = oRecips.Add("testCC@testmail.com");
            oCCRecip.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olCC;
            oCCRecip.Resolve();

            //Add Subject
            oMailItem.Subject = "Test Mail";

            // body, bcc etc...
            oMailItem.Body = "Email body content here \nThis is a new line.";

            //Display the mailbox
            oMailItem.Display(true);
            var time = DateTime.Now;
            tbLast_email_update.Text = time.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception objEx)
        {
            Response.Write(objEx.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say "on the server" do you mean as a background process? ["Microsoft does not recommend or support server-side Automation of Office."](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) (Your error is in the "common errors may occur" list there.) There are probably Exchange APIs you can use instead.

Comment: You need to have an outlook account setup on PC for the code to run.  The FROM address on the EMAIL also must match the Windows Credentials that are used to login to the computer.  You can setup a user account on the server to process the emails but the FROM address will be the new account and not the account of the users.

Comment: Or if you do not need Exchange support use MailKit (Or SmtpClient)

Comment: When I say "on the server" I mean it is deployed to a server and I get to it via the server URL, rather than running it on my local machine. I'll check out that link, thanks!